# Why the UIButton is so big in a simulator?

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController and a UIButton under it. Here is the screenshot of my storyboard.

[image: Storyboard]

When I build the app, the button is huge:

[image]

All of my constraints were set automatically. I tried to specify the height, but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

P.S. I'm using XCode 6.3.

**Edit:**

**ViewController.swift**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var restartButton: UIButton!
    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
    var pageTitles: NSArray!
    var pageImages: NSArray!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pageTitles = NSArray(objects: "Page 1", "Page 2")
        self.pageImages = NSArray(objects: "algorithm", "apoint")

        self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

        var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController
        var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - restartButton.frame.height)

        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
        self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(self.pageViewController.view)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ContentViewController {
        if ((self.pageTitles.count == 0) || (index >= self.pageTitles.count)) {
            return ContentViewController()
        }

        var vc: ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController
        vc.imageFile = self.pageImages[index] as! String
        vc.titleText = self.pageTitles[index] as! String
        vc.pageIndex = index

        return vc
    }

    @IBAction func restartAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController
        var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)
        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
        var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

        if (index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound) {
            return nil
        }

        index--
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
        var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

        if index == NSNotFound {
            return nil
        }

        index++

        if index == self.pageTitles.count {
            return nil
        }

        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return self.pageTitles.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

}
```

Comment: i would remove all of the constraints and re-set them myself

Comment: @DanBeaulieu I tried. I'm not sure how to set constraints between the button and UIPageViewController. For now, I did autoconstraints and then do 

**self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - helloWorldButton.frame.height)**

in order to give the space for the button.

Comment: If you created your buttons programmatically you should post some of your code. I thought you created it in Xcode's storyboard designer. I am not sure if my answer will actually help you.

Comment: Edit your question to show your code.

Comment: @matt added the code. restartButton is the one I'm having an issue with.

Comment: @jackson Thanks but I don't see any code there that would affect the size of `restartButton`. But maybe you have constraints from `restartButton` to something else whose size is being changed by that code? If so, get rid of them!

Comment: @matt I do not manually modify the size of the button. That's the confusion.

Comment: See my wild guess answer below! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the problem is that you have a constraint from the top of the button to something else in the interface. Get rid of that constraint. The only constraints you need for a button at the bottom of the screen are its bottom and its right-or-left-or-center - its width and height are automatic.

Comment: I like when that happens! :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to find your button in your Controller Scene like this, highlight your constraints and delete them.

[image]

Personally when I have constraint issues, I start from scratch by deleting all of the constraints across the board. This is just my personal approach.

Next thing I do is start with the item at the top of my storyboard view and set its constraints like this:

[image]

Notice in my add constraints window i am only selecting the **top** and **left** margins and the **width** and **height**. I do this to each of my objects starting from the top of the screen and working my way to the bottom.

Obviously you'll need to play with this feature a bit to get your desired results. Please note that what I've provided is just an example and not a fix-all.

---

**edit:**

after reading your comment I am not sure this solution will help you, I didn't realize that you made your button programmatically. I'm going to leave it up for the time being.

Comment: Sorry, the button was created in a storyboard. The only thing I did programatically is changing the size of UIPageViewController, by reducing its height to the height of a button, i.e. **pageViewController.height - button.height**. I just checked constraints for the button, it only has "width", no height though.

Comment: try setting a height and width in your "Add New Constraints" pane like I did in the picture, it should constrain the size of your button